# Power BI - Data Refresh Error Connecting to Azure DevOps Analytics Service - The import VSTS.AnalyticsViews matches no exports

Tags: azure, azure-devops, powerbi, azure-analysis-services

Quick overview of what I've done:

- Created a Power BI dashboard with data from our Azure DevOps board.
- The data source is the Azure DevOps Service, and it's connecting to an analytics view.
- The data refresh works when I open the dashboard in desktop, and click refresh.
- Setup a data refresh schedule on the server, and I get the following error:

**SessionID: de7ed32e-b566-4813-b9ca-eacbc25bac04
[0] -1055784932: The import VSTS.AnalyticsViews matches no exports. Did you miss a module reference?. The exception was raised by the IDbCommand interface.
[1] -1055129594: The current operation was cancelled because another operation in the transaction failed.**

Both the desktop and server versions are January 2019.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!
Jenny

Comment: Based on the error message, the data you refreshed may not be mached with the data you import, please check if the data in data source is changed the data type.You can view  this similar [issue](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Service/lt-pi-gt-The-import-0CALMONTH-matches-no-exports-Did-you-miss-a/td-p/595424) and also try asking the [Power BI](https://community.powerbi.com/) Community for more help.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for the advice. I took out the changed data type of the Created Date field. I was hoping it was as simple as that, but turns out it isn't. I'm getting more errors now. The first two I was getting before, plus a third line that repeats, "The current operation was cancelled because another operation in the transaction failed."

I've looked through many articles searching both the Azure and Power BI sides of the data source. I haven't found anything helpful. I just left a voicemail with our Customer Success Manager. If he passes along any insight. I will share it here. Thanks!

Comment: I found out why this doesn't work after troubleshooting with Microsoft for 2 days. I need Power BI Pro. Our IT is getting a license for me, and I'll post the full solution once I set it up.